# bash completion script that susbtitute to another command

Tags: bash, autocomplete, tab-completion

I want to make a "completion script" that substitutes a virtual command (`g`) to another command (`cd`).

I want `g dl<Tab>` to dynamically transform into `cd ~/dl/`.

An alias is not what I want, because I want to continue typing. The `g`'s argument is retrieved using [a key/value store](https://github.com/Gumnos/kv.awk)

I tried to assign values to the `$COMP_WORDS` array to change user written text, but it doesn't works :

```sh
_g_completions() {
    local FILE="$HOME/.config/kv.awk/bookmarks.txt"
    local COMPLEN="${#COMP_WORDS[@]}"
    if [ "${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}" -lt 3 ]
    then
        # list keys
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(awk '/^[A-Za-z]/ {print tolower($1)}' "$FILE")" -- "$CURRENT"))
    else
        # subsitute command
        COMP_WORDS[0]="cd"
        COMP_WORDS[1]="$(kv.awk bookmarks get "${COMP_WORDS[1]}")"
    fi
}

complete -F _g_completions g
```

Comment: Doesn't seem possible. Why would word completion work on the whole command line anyways?

Comment: It could correct mistakes, for example. Or provide a dynamic alias, as I'm trying to do.

Comment: Both are beyond the definition of *completion*